# Can we automatically open a second tab with IE8 with another browser (IE6 Virtual)

Tags: vmware-player, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

AT the company I work with they have legacy applications that work only with IE6 with no plan to upgrading them. The company will be rolling out IE8, the solution was to rollout IE6 Virtual (VMWare) that virtualises IE6 as it can't be installed along with IE8.

Is there a way with IE8 (or plugin) that will automatically open Virtual IE6 if a website is known to work with Virtual IE6 only. I know it's possible with FireFox plugin. Wasn't sure if it's possible with ie8

Comment: The compatibility view doesn't work ?